# $scope.$apply not applying changes to ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a websocket which I use to log the operation of my application, and am trying to display this data to the user. The page only seems to display the first log message sent through the socket after the controller loads.

In the controller:

```
$scope.$on('log-update', function(event, args){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.log = $sce.trustAsHtml(args.newLog);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="logPanel" style="height: 807px; overflow: scroll;" ng-bind-html="log"></div>
```

I've confirmed that the scope does receive all the socket messages, and it's just a binding issue.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to manually call a digest cycle inside `$scope.$on()`. Are you sure the event is really sent?

Comment: Yes, console logging shows that args.newLog is definitely being sent at the appropriate times

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle reproducing the problem?